# Opencart - Categories always expanded

Tags: php, javascript, html, module, opencart

How can I always display subcategories? I want this module on the left showing always the same - all parent and their children categories..

Answer (score 0):

In the file `catalog\controller\module\category.php`, replace the following:

```
if ($category_id == $result['category_id']) {
    $children = $this->getCategories($result['category_id'], $new_path);
}
```

...with:

```
//if ($category_id == $result['category_id']) {
      $children = $this->getCategories($result['category_id'], $new_path);    
//}
```

Source: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3128&p=25921&#p25921

For Opencart 2 this is the solution

[OpenCart 2: Show all subcategories in category module by default (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442713/opencart-2-show-all-subcategories-in-category-module-by-default-php)